# Problem with Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function isOembed(url) {
    var pattern = /http:\/\/(.*youtube\.com\/watch.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/v\/.*|youtu\.be\/.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/user\/.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/.*#.*\/.*|m\.youtube\.com\/watch.*|m\.youtube\.com\/index.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/profile.*/;
    return pattern.test(url);
}

alert(isOembed('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9W8Ie4MyRX0&feature=related'));
```

Why does the following regex produce nothing? I've tried it in jsFiddle.

The lint says:

```
Error:
Problem at line 2 character 223: Unescaped '/'.
var pattern =/http:\/\/(.*youtube\.com\/watch.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/v\/.*|y...

Implied global: alert 6
```

Comment: You can post that comment as an [answer to your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions). G'wan, try it. You know you wanna.

Answer (score 1):

jonnnnnnnnnie was right, just add a ) at end of the regex, like this:
http://jsbin.com/ufufed/2/

```js
var pattern = /http:\/\/(.*youtube\.com\/watch.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/v\/.*|youtu\.be\/.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/user\/.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/.*#.*\/.*|m\.youtube\.com\/watch.*|m\.youtube\.com\/index.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/profile.*)/;
```